# Standardising json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, httparty

I am using HTTParty to call the Flickr API. I get a response but it's escaped. How can I get plain and simple json?>

```
class Flickr

  require 'httparty'
  include HTTParty

  API_KEY         = '2e18b933c285b552701e7c6f5bff3aee'
  SECRET          = '88123767bb4492b2'
  USER_ID         = '57951266@N03'
  RESPONSE_FORMAT = 'json'
  base_uri          'http://api.flickr.com'

  # Get list of all collections
  def self.collections_list
    response = get("/services/rest/",
      :query => {
        method:          'flickr.collections.getTree',
        api_key:         API_KEY,
        user_id:         USER_ID,
        format:          RESPONSE_FORMAT,
        nojsoncallback:  1
      }
    )

    response.body

  end
```

Here is what `response.body` returns: How can I disable the escaping that prevents it from being valid json?

=> "{\"collections\":{\"collection\":[{\"id\":\"579244212-72157632934521433434033423\", \"title\":\"mysite.co.uk\", \"description\":\"\", \"iconlarge\":\"\/images\/collection_default_l.gif\", \"iconsmall\":\"\/images\/collection_default_s.gif\", \"collection\":[{\"id\":\"5723456928212-72157634949706778\", \"title\":\"Holidays\", \"description\":\"\", \"iconlarge\":\"\/images\/collection_default_l.gif\", \"iconsmall\":\"\/images\/collection_default_s.gif\", \"collection\":[{\"id\":\"5792364528212-7215763492346543457291\", \"title\":\"Standard\", \"description\":\"\", \"iconlarge\":\"\/images\/collection_default_l.gif\", \"iconsmall\":\"\/images\/collection_default_s.gif\", \"set\":[{\"id\":\"72157628982366181735\", \"title\":\"Paris Trip\", \"description\":\"11th-13th May 2008 - (Peeps)\"}, {\"id\":\"72157629097324306\", \"title\":\"Ohio\", \"description\":\"August 2005 - (Peeps)\"}, {\"id\":\"72157629097297760\", \"title\":\"Iceland Holiday\", \"description\":\"5th-16th Aug 2004 - (Peeps)\"}]}, {\"id\":\"57928212-236572157629691182748\", \"title\":\"1 - Trip\", \"description\":\"\", \"iconlarge\":\"\/images\/collection_default_l.gif\", \"iconsmall\":\"\/images\/collection_default_s.gif\", \"set\":[{\"id\":\"72157629683532365562\", \"title\":\"Day 1\", \"description\":\"\"}, {\"id\":\"72157629683246523541696\", \"title\":\"Day 2\", \"description\":\"\"}, {\"id\":\"7215762968234563554852\", \"title\":\"Day 3\", \"description\":\"\"}, {\"id\":\"7215762972346510465912\", \"title\":\"Day 4\", \"description\":\"\"}, {\"id\":\"72157362629710474644\", \"title\":\"Day 5 South\", \"description\":\"\"}, {\"id\":\"7215762923564710489442\", \"title\":\"Day 6 \", \"description\":\"\"}, {\"id\":\"721576292346834618028\", \"title\":\"Day 7 i\", \"description\":\"\"}, {\"id\":\"721576265349834637138\", \"title\":\"Day 8\", \"description\":\"\"}, {\"id\":\"72157629236836419418\", \"title\":\"Day 9\", \"description\":\"\"}, {\"id\":\"7215762985641123596\", \"title\":\"Day 10\", \"description\":\"\"}, {\"id\":\"72157629854631700916\", \"title\":\"Day 11 & 12\", \"description\":\"\"}, {\"id\":\"721576223649851713058\", \"title\":\"Day 13,14 & 15 -\", \"description\":\"\"}]}, {\"id\":\"57928212-72236157629866347760\", \"title\":\"2 - Trip 2010\", \"description\":\"\", \"iconlarge\":\"\/images\/collection_default_l.gif\", \"iconsmall\":\"\/images\/collection_default_s.gif\", \"set\":[{\"id\":\"721576292346866337538\", \"title\":\"Day 0 - Arrival   ....

Comment: Could consider looking at: https://github.com/hoxworth/json-schema not sure if that is what you'd be after though

Comment: `to_json` and `JSON.parse` are more or less inverse operations. I'm not sure what you are trying to do. What do you mean with "proper json"?

Comment: I don't think that is what I am after. I wish to turn my response into valid json. json doesn't support square brackets and to hash arrows "=>" as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 1):

`response.to_json` will give you proper JSON.  `JSON.parse(response.to_json)` will turn that JSON into a ruby hash of hashes/arrays/etc.

Comment: ah right ok. When I do response.to_json. A lot of the single and double quotes are escaped. How can this be solved? Also what is the best way of looping through this result set once I have the valid json with no escaped characters?

Comment: Are you sure they are escaped?  If you're doing this in the console that can happen, but it's only for display.  As for looping through it.. really depends on what data is being returned.

Comment: I will update my OP now to show the json returned from Flickr that is in response.body

Comment: @rctneil  Are you sure it's being escaped?  That looks an awful lot like what IRB outputs by default.  What happens if you do `response.to_json.class`.  I imagine you'll get a Hash.

Comment: My mistake.  If response.body is returning a string, then just pass that into JSON.parse and you should get a Ruby hash.

Comment: Any more thoughts on this?

Comment: @rctneil I think you'd be best served by opening up the rails console and stepping through each piece of the API call and result to see what type of objects you have and when.

Comment: I ran the API call in a Chrome extension HTTP client and it returns valid json. But when attempting the call in my rails app via HTTParty I get the escaped version. Same arguments and everything.

Comment: Still trying to solve this. I have simplified as much as I can and it MUST be a Rails/Ruby thing as when the call is made outside of R and R, I get a nice valid response. I will update my OP with the full Flickr class I have and an example of the output I am getting. All I need is plain and simple json. Nothing more and nothing less.